# How to use tabs in angular2

Tags: angular, tabs

I have an application that uses angular2 with routes.ts properly set.
In the app, I have navbar set according to the routes defined in routes.ts.

In one of the route, I want to use a tab that does not refer to routes.ts
but instead I want it to refer to the tab-content class.

When I tried to run my application, I got an error that said the route is not defined in the routes.ts.

How do I make tabs that refer to tab-content class instead of routes.ts?

app.component.ts code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

import { FooterComponent, HEADER_DIRECTIVES, NAVBAR_DIRECTIVES } from 'ui-core/core';

import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { PrintJobComponent } from './components/printJob/printJob.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-template',
  template: `
    <cui-header title="Sample App">
      <cui-navbar>
        <cui-navbar-item route="/printJob">Print Job</cui-navbar-item>
        <cui-navbar-item route="/home">Home</cui-navbar-item>
      </cui-navbar>
    </cui-header>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <cui-footer [helpRoutePath]="helpRoutePath"></cui-footer>
`,
  directives: [FooterComponent, HEADER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, NAVBAR_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class AppComponent {

}
```

routes.ts:

```
/**
 * angular2 imports
 */
import { RouterConfig, provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

/**
 * App Component imports
 */
import { HomeComponent } from './app/components/home/home.component';
import { PrintJobComponent } from './app/components/printJob/printJob.component';

export const APP_ROUTES: RouterConfig = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'printJob', component: PrintJobComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
    provideRouter(APP_ROUTES)
];
```

printJob.component.ts code:

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'print-job',
  template: `
  <div class="container-fluid single-col-full-width-container">
    <br>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#printJobTab">Print Job</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#reprintJobTab">Reprint Job</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
      <div id="printJobTab" class="tab-pane fade">
        <p>table for print job here.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="reprintJobTab" class="tab-pane fade">
        <p>table for reprint job here.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
`
})
export class PrintJobComponent {

}
```

Comment: Can you post some code? What do you mean with not refering to routes.ts?

Comment: I have posted some codes. When I clicked on printJobTab in printJob.component.ts, it creates a console error: Error: Cannot match any routes: 'printJobTab'

Comment: why dont you use a routerlink? <a   [routerLink]="['printJobTag']"

Comment: used routerLink but still have error

Answer (score 0):

You have a path printJob and route to printJobTab

So routing like this will probably work:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/printJob']">Print Job</a>
<a [routerLink]="['/home']">Home</a>
```

Here you have a working plunker using the lastes Angular  version.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Ppll3PmpCiURmmaRDce8?p=preview

Comment: this is still using routes.

Comment: is there a way that href in children of nav-tabs will refer to tab-content class under the same template in the .ts file?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You can show/hide content using ngIf via nav tabs. But routing is the best practice. What's wrong with routes?

Comment: I'm just used to use tabs in bootstrap. it is easier.